# how to display an object on a click event in angular 2/4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

When i click a button i want to display a user name using interpolation into a waiting list. My html code for the button is here.

```
<button (click) = "onWaitListSubmit(user)">Add to waiting list</button>

<h2 class="page-header">{{user.name}}</h2>
```

my appcomponent.ts code is here. How do i get the button to display the user name when i click it?

```
export class AppComponent{

"user": "name"

onWaitListSubmit(user){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h2 *ngIf="show" class="page-header">{{user.name}}</h2>
```

```
show:boolean = false;

onWaitListSubmit(user){
  this.show = true;
}
```

You an also just use

```
<h2 class="page-header">{{user?.name}}</h2>
```

```
onWaitListSubmit(user){
  this.user = {name: 'foo'};
}
```

then `{{user.name}}` will only show the name when `this.user` actually has a value.